# Typescript Exclude Null in Types

Tags: typescript

```
class Foo<T = null> {
    add<U>() {
        return this as any as Foo<T extends null ? U : T & U>;
    }

    test(v: T) {
    }
}

const foo = new Foo;
foo.test(null);
foo.add<{value: string}>().test(null); // wrong
foo.add<{value: string}>().test({value: 'string'});
```

`foo.test` still can use `null` as argument in last line.

Is `T extends null` wrong condition for check about `T` equal `null`?
What is correct way for it?

Comment: Do you have strict null checks enabled ? I tried in the playground, and when you enable strictNullChecks i get an error http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%3CT%20%3D%20null%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%3CU%3E()%20%7Breturn%20this%20as%20any%20as%20Foo%3CT%20extends%20null%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20T%20%26%20U%3E%3B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test(v%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo%3B%0D%0Afoo.add%3C%7Bvalue%3A%20string%7D%3E().test(null)%3B%20%2F%2F%20wrong%0D%0Afoo.add%3C%7Bvalue%3A%20string%7D%3E().test(%7Bvalue%3A%20'string'%7D)%3B

Comment: It's Fixed with modified `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Add Option to `tsconfig.js`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true
    }
}
```